# HDFS copyFromLocal slow when using ssh

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using ssh to issue a copyFromLocal command of HDFS like this (in a script):

`ssh -t ubuntu@namenode_server "hdfs dfs -copyFromlocal data/file.csv /file.csv"`

However, I am observing very peculiar behavior. This ssh command can take a variable time from 20 min to 25 min for a 9GB file. However, if I simply delete the file from HDFS and rerun the command, it always executes within 4 min.

The transfer of the file also takes around 3-4 min when moving it from one HDFS cluster to another as well (even when I change the block size between source and destination clusters).

I am using EC2 servers for the HDFS cluster. I am using Hadoop 2.7.6.

Not sure why it takes such a long time to copy the file from local file system to HDFS the first time.

Comment: When you delete the file, are you skipping the Trash or otherwise expunging it?

Comment: Simply using the hdfs dfs -rm to remove the file and the default trash policy which I suppose has the deletion interval = 0 min